# How to share an Internet connection over Bluetooth from the Phone to the PC

Tags: bluetooth, connection

I am on vacation and have a phone (N900) with an Internet connection. I have no Internet connection for my laptop. I'd like to connect the phone and laptop over Bluetooth (second choice: per USB cable) and share the connection with the laptop. I seem to remember that I was offered such a sharing the first time I connected the devices, but now I unpaired and paired them again and can't get this window to show again. Any ideas how to set it up? Google only shows hits for the other way round (the Ubuntu PC has the Internet).

Sorry if the question has been asked before, the search function does not work with the phone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that the connection sharing has to be enabled on the phone. I installed an app on the phone which shares the connection (for the N900, it is called bluetooth-dun) and on the new pairing, Ubuntu automatically offered to use the phone's Internet connection. I guess that I must have seen the option when pairing with somebody else's phone before.

Then it showed a wizard for the setup (choosing a provider and a plan) and after I filled it out, it worked. At least that's how it works on 11.04.