# How do you share Internet from an Android tablet to a laptop/pc with bluetooth?

Tags: networking, bluetooth, android, connection-sharing

My tablet offers me the option to share internet via bluetooth, which is interesting because the laptop has no ethernet cable socket, and wireless stopped working after an upgrade, and sharing with usb is not possible.

But where do I start on actually receiving internet on the laptop?  Using 16.04.

Update; This question seems to ask about the same, but does not offer any help on the specifics on how to do it: [How to share an Internet connection over Bluetooth from the Phone to the PC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55903/how-to-share-an-internet-connection-over-bluetooth-from-the-phone-to-the-pc)

Answer (score 0):

You should look for Bluetooth tethering settings on Your tablet. After enabling it, You should check Your computer if it supports PAN profile in user role.

The first part is very easy, but the second one might be hard. I'd check if BlueZ in version on Your system supports PAN.

Comment: Yeah, it's the second part I am asking about.  Getting the tablet to share seems straight-forward.  But on the Ubuntu side I don't even know where to start.